# How do I refresh a model in ember.js after I have added a record with createRecord()?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

**UPDATE: This is outdated, my blog is not Ember-based anymore.** Basically, my question is simple. I added a record with `createRecord()`. I can see the `didCreate` event fired, but I don't know how to make ember load and display what I have just created. This case is about adding a comment to an post -- that is what I want to see instantly.

**UPDATE**: I have no jsfiddle, but I can show off the live app/site I am talking about is my own blog, here: http://eduardmoldovan.com/

The templates are at the bottom of the page, the javascript is here: http://eduardmoldovan.com/static/eduardmoldovan.com/javascripts/ngin.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can manually add your new record to array of records from the `didCreate` hook:</strike>

```
var newRecord = transaction.createRecord(Ngin.Comment, {
    articleUrl: articleUrl,
    name: name,
    url: url,
    email: email,
    body: body,
    secret: secret
});
newRecord.one('didCreate', this, function () {
    this.get('comments').pushObject(newRecord);
});
transaction.commit();
```

Or, if you want to reload from server, use the `reload` method:

```
controller.get("comments").reload();
```

#### Edit

After examining sourcecode I found an `update` method in class `RecordArray`. It seems to be the right one.

Comment: None of those works. First one says that server response is immutable, second one says that reload is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have used commit() to save the comment, something like this should work:

```
{{#each comment in post.comments}}
  {{comment.text}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: ok. if things are wired up correctly it should be updating automatically, but there is plenty that could be going wrong in between. impossible to guess, suggest posting a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The following is neither efficient nor the best method but it will notify the view. And will try to find a better method. Im sure theres an update method and one that notifies the view. Cannot find it immediately.

template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
<button {{action 'newObject'}} ></button>
```

controller

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend

  actions: {
    newObject: function() {
       this.store.createRecord('post', {id: xxxx, title: 'Default title'});
       var all = this.store.filter('post', function(post) {
         return post; // return each object
       }); //This filter will include the new post record
       this.set('model', all); // set will notify the view of a mutated array
    }
  },
```

Comment: and still not liking this hack.